# Select2 populate a second field based on first (multi)selection using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

How can i achieve this?
I have this first multiple select option field (parentfield) and i need to popupate a second one(childfield) based on values of the first one

```
<select id="parentfield" name="parentfield[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">first value</option>
    <option value="2">second value</option>
    <option value="3">third value</option>
</select>
```

This parentfield should post values to a php script and the script return data to the childfield like this

```
<select id="childfield" name="childfield[]">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option value="1">first value child</option>
        <option value="2">second value child</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option value="3">third value child</option>
        <option value="4">fourth value child</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

So i have this php code that return a json, that i want to use to build the values
(Obs.: its a joomla ajax request in a custom component)

```
<?php
$materiaspost = implode(',',JRequest::getVar('disciplina'));
$materias = carregarcampos('SELECT * FROM #__marqueicerto_materias WHERE disciplina IN ('.$materiaspost.') AND assunto=0 ORDER BY materia ASC','list');
foreach ($materias as $materia) {
    $submaterias = carregarcampos('SELECT * FROM #__marqueicerto_materias WHERE assunto='.$materia['id_materia'].' ORDER BY materia ASC','list');
    foreach ($submaterias as $submateria) {
        // $vetor[$materia['materia']][$submateria['materia']] = array($submateria['id_materia']=>$submateria['materia']);
        $vetor[$materia['materia']][$submateria['id_materia']] = $submateria['materia'];
    }
}
?>
```

How should look my jquery to achieve this?
Do i have to modify my php code to generate a diferent json response?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple drop down list </title>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='yourcurrentfilename.php?cat=' + val ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?Php

$cat=$_GET['cat']; 

$quer2="SELECT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"; 

if(isset($cat)){
$quer1="SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"; 
}

echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($cat_name = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) {
if($cat_name['cat_id']==$cat){
    echo "<option selected value=".$cat_name['cat_id'].">".$cat_name['category']."</option>"."<BR>";
}
else{
    echo  "<option value=".$cat_name['cat_id'].">".$cat_name['category']."</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select Two</option>";
while($subcat_name = mysql_fetch_array($quer1)) {
echo  "<option value=".$subcat_name['subcategory'].">".$subcat_name['subcategory']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```